# How can you plot a value in PYTEARCAT?

Tags: python, computational-physics, plotting, tensor, calculus

I've been working with Tensor calculus using the Python module PYTEARCAT. (See: https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.15016 and https://github.com/pytearcat/pytearcat.) It calculates quantities such as the Ricci curvature and Einstein tensor from a metric tensor, and this part works just fine for me. However, I can't seem to find a way to plot any quantities or components of any of the calculated tensors with respect to some coordinates (Such as plotting the 0,0 component of an Einstein tensor with respect to x and t). I'm wondering if there's some way to use Sympy (or some other module) to plot these quantities, as doing so would be very helpful. On a related note, I have also tried printing individual components of a tensor using indices (i.e. Ein[0][0]), but it just says that 'Tensor objects are non-iterable', which might be a problem as well since these are the objects I want to plot. So, if anyone has experience with PYTEARCAT--or is just good with code and doesn't mind looking at the links above--how would you go about plotting tensor components calculated by this module?